# PyCharm: How to run behave.exe?

Tags: python, behavior, pycharm

I want to use behave lib in my program. I write code as in [behave-tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#features).
But, when I "Run" my tutorial-project, I see in PyCharm-console:

```
C:\Python27\virtualenv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharmProjects/tutorial/steps/tutorial.py"
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think what I must to use behave.exe for run my project:

```
C:\Python27\virtualenv\Scripts\behave.exe
```

How to get it?

Comment: PyCharm has no Behave support yet: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8427. You can use [external tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) to run custom executables as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you!
I add "behave.exe" to External tools.

Comment: If I add behave.exe as External tool giving it a path to my feature folder as working directory, for another project I have to add ANOTHER External tool record with a different working directory?

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your run as per your purpose please have a look to screenhots here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

taken from: http://automated-testing.info/t/bdd-framework-debug-testov-stepov/3392/3

Comment: The instructions from @mykhailo-poliarush worked for me, but instead of `behave-script.py` I had to find and run the `behave` script. In my virtual environment this was:  
  
~/.virtualenvs/my_project_virtualenv/bin/behave  
  
(Note: I'm using behave==1.2.3 on a Mac)

Answer (score 3):

Even though `behave` support is [now in the Professional Edition](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/), it's [currently not in the Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

You can still call the `behave` module for a given feature directory.

Add a Python Run configuration, with no script and these options:

> `Interpreter options: -m behave`
>   `Working directory: path/to/feature/directory`

Answer (score 2):

I tinkered around with previous answers and got PyCharm CE 5.x working with Behave I have python 2.7 installed system-wide, and *behave* installed via PyCharm package management
Here is my run config:
**Script**: put dot (**.**) in here [*this way PyCharm recognizes the configuration as valid and doesn't show red cross mark]*

**Working Directory** points to the dirctory where *.feature* file is
**Interpreter options:** -m behave

Answer (score 2):

For PyCharm **Community** 2016.3 on mac, setup a run configuration with:

- **Script**: `/usr/local/bin/behave`
- **Script Parameters**: `path/to/feature/directory`
- **Working Directory**: `path/to/project/directory`

This way the run & DEBUG both work.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 features file (createX.feature and createY.feature) at feature directory but I want to select only 1

My configuration is

- Script: createY.feature
- Script parameters: --tags=@int --tags=@e2e
- Interpreter options: -m behave
- Working directory: $features_directory

The "Run" window shows this execution command

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -m behave createY.feature --tags=@int --tags=@e2e
```

but pycharm chooses **the other** feature file :(

But if I run the command at a terminal window, the command works!!

Edit: I have changed the feature file I want to execute for a better understanding: I try to execute the last one following alphabetical order

Edit 2: **Solved** It seems that *behave* does not like to have "scratch" files for control tasks at steps directory ... Once I deleted them, that handsome configuration works!!